# Cannot send bundle from Activity to Fragment in NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to send a bundle with a HashMap called jsonList from the Main activity:

```
public Bundle authBundle(){

    jsonList = EndpointsParser.parseJSON(endpoints);
    extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putSerializable("ParsedList", jsonList);
    return extras;
}


@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position))
            .commit();
    extras = authBundle();
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            OverviewFragment overviewFragment = new OverviewFragment();
            overviewFragment.setArguments(extras);
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, OverviewFragment.newInstance(position)).commit();
            break;
```

to a Fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Bundle extras = getArguments();
    Serializable parsedList = extras.getSerializable("ParsedList");
    jsonList = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>)parsedList;
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_overview, container, false);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.overviewRV);

    return rootView;
    }
```

However no matter what I try, the Bundle always gets to the fragment with no data. After debugging I can see the data on "overviewFragment.setArguments(extras)" at the Activity switch right before the fragment manager calls the fragment but it just doesn't get there.

I apologize in advance if it's too obvious but this is my very first app and I just can't get it to work. I'd really appreciate some help.

UPDATE:

I managed to get the data across to the fragment by adding the commented line bellow:

```
switch (position) {
        case 0:
            OverviewFragment overviewFragment = new OverviewFragment();
            overviewFragment.setArguments(extras);
            //fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container,overviewFragment).commit();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, OverviewFragment.newInstance(position)).commit();
            break;
```

However my list doesn't scroll anymore and the items don't respond to click. It seems it inflates 2 fragments in the same place and blocks all interactions. Apparently ".replace" doesn't send the bundle. Any ideas?

Comment: jsonList certain this isnt empty?

Comment: Yeah, I checked. Right before the fragment call, this is the value of the Extras Bundle: "Bundle[{ParsedList=[{region=regionOne, type=compute, publicURL=http://server1:8774/v2/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, name=nova}, {region=regionOne, type=network, publicURL=http://server1:9696, name=neutron},... "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it working with an "Add" and then a "Replace":

```
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position))
            .commit();
    extras = authBundle();
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            OverviewFragment overviewFragment = new OverviewFragment();
            overviewFragment.setArguments(extras);
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, OverviewFragment.newInstance(position)).commit();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,overviewFragment).commit();
            break;
```